# Constant pool error

Tags: java, byte-code

To debug a jar file, i tried to modify java bytecode using JByteMod tool and print some variable to standard output. The variable i'm trying to print is an `ArrayList`. Specifically, it's a public attribute of class `MethodNode`, named `outgoings_`. The code is something like this:

```
invokeinterface Object Iterator.next()
checkcast MethodNode
astore 4
######## my code begins from here #######
getstatic PrintStream System.out
aload 4
getfield List MethodNode.outgoings_
invokevirtual void PrintStream.println(Object)
```

The above code works fine and actually prints the list. For some reasons, i needed to print the first element of that list, so i changed the code:

```
invokeinterface Object Iterator.next()
checkcast MethodNode
astore 4
######## my code begins from here #######
getstatic PrintStream System.out
aload 4
getfield List MethodNode.outgoings_
iconst_0
invokeinterface Object List.get(int)
invokevirtual void PrintStream.println(Object)
```

But this code fails to run and outputs this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 67 in class wy2.SCCUtil
Exception Details:
  Location:
    wy2/SCCUtil.buildScc(Lwy/CallGraph;)V @51: invokeinterface
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 67 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: bb00 1f59 b700 204d bb00 1659 b700 174e
    0x0000010: 2bb4 0026 b900 2c01 003a 05a7 0029 1905
    0x0000020: b900 3401 00c0 0036 3a04 b200 3c19 04b4
    0x0000030: 003f 03b9 0043 0200 b600 492a 2b19 042c
    0x0000040: 2db6 004d 1905 b900 5101 009a ffd3 2db9
    0x0000050: 0054 0100 a700 6f2c b600 57c0 0036 3a04
    0x0000060: 2d19 04b9 005b 0200 9900 06a7 0058 bb00
    0x0000070: 5d59 b700 5e3a 052a 2b19 042d 1905 b400
    0x0000080: 61b6 0065 1905 b400 61b9 0066 0100 3a07
    0x0000090: a700 1d19 07b9 0034 0100 c000 363a 062a
    0x00000a0: b400 1419 0619 05b9 006c 0300 5719 07b9
    0x00000b0: 0051 0100 9aff df2a b400 1919 05b9 006f
    0x00000c0: 0200 572c b600 7299 ff90 2ab4 0019 b900
    0x00000d0: 6601 003a 05a7 0107 1905 b900 3401 00c0
    0x00000e0: 005d 3a04 1904 b400 61b9 0066 0100 3a07
    0x00000f0: a700 d319 07b9 0034 0100 c000 363a 0619
    0x0000100: 06b4 003f b900 2c01 003a 09a7 004c 1909
    0x0000110: b900 3401 00c0 0036 3a08 2bb4 0026 1908
    0x0000120: b900 7302 009a 0006 a700 2f2a b400 1419
    0x0000130: 08b9 0076 0200 1904 a600 06a7 001c 1904
    0x0000140: b400 782a b400 1419 08b9 0076 0200 c000
    0x0000150: 5db9 006f 0200 5719 09b9 0051 0100 9aff
    0x0000160: b019 06b4 007b b900 2c01 003a 09a7 004c
    0x0000170: 1909 b900 3401 00c0 0036 3a08 2bb4 0026
    0x0000180: 1908 b900 7302 009a 0006 a700 2f2a b400
    0x0000190: 1419 08b9 0076 0200 1904 a600 06a7 001c
    0x00001a0: 1904 b400 7e2a b400 1419 08b9 0076 0200
    0x00001b0: c000 5db9 006f 0200 5719 09b9 0051 0100
    0x00001c0: 9aff b019 07b9 0051 0100 9aff 2919 0419
    0x00001d0: 04b4 0078 b900 8201 00b5 0086 1905 b900
    0x00001e0: 5101 009a fef5 b1                      
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@30,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Top,Object[#48]},{})
    same_frame(@68)
    chop_frame(@87,2)
    append_frame(@110,Object[#54])
    append_frame(@147,Object[#93],Top,Object[#48])
    same_frame(@173)
    full_frame(@195,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46]},{})
    append_frame(@216,Top,Object[#48])
    full_frame(@243,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Top,Object[#48]},{})
    full_frame(@270,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48],Top,Object[#48]},{})
    full_frame(@299,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48]},{})
    same_frame(@318)
    full_frame(@343,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48],Top,Object[#48]},{})
    same_frame(@368)
    full_frame(@397,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48]},{})
    same_frame(@416)
    full_frame(@441,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Object[#54],Object[#48],Top,Object[#48]},{})
    full_frame(@451,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Object[#93],Object[#48],Top,Object[#48]},{})
    full_frame(@476,{Object[#2],Object[#34],Object[#31],Object[#46],Top,Object[#48]},{})

    at wy2.Util.buildMethodHash2(Util.java:132)
    at wy2.Util.doIt(Util.java:29)
    at wy2.Main.genData(Main.java:68)
    at wy2.Main.main(Main.java:59)
    ... 5 more
```

What i'm doing wrong? Is it a JByteMod bug?

**EDIT:**

Here are the links to the class file [before](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw5myx9hjy6zjj8/SCCUtil.class?dl=0) and [after](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pj2whfmb32s7ge3/SCCUtil-modified.class?dl=0) modification.

Comment: Most likely it is a JByteMod bug, but there's no way to know for sure unless you post the (binary) classfiles before and after modification.

Comment: @Antimony I added links to the class file before and after modification. Is there any other better tool around? I also tried JBE but it seems have problems saving newly added bytecodes.

Comment: Pelase report this issue to the tool author, they're in better position to determine if it's bug or not. In the meantime you can try Krakatau.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that constant pool entry 67 (the one for your List.get()) method has the type `Method`, rather than `InterfaceMethod`, even though you are trying to invoke it as an interface method. When using `invokeinterface`, the corresponding constant pool entries need to be `InterfaceMethod`.

Assuming you didn't specify the type itself, this is likely a bug in the tool you used. You may want to try using the [Krakatau assembler/disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) instead.

When using Krakatau, the constant pool type is specified after the invoke instruction. For example, on the following line of the disassembly for your class, `Method` should be changed to `InterfaceMethod`.

```
L51:    invokeinterface Method java/util/List get (I)Ljava/lang/Object; 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your comment *(Would respond as a comment, but don't have the 50 rep yet)*:

> I added links to the class file before and after modification. *Is there any other better tool around?*

I develop the bytecode editor [Recaf](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf). I [reimplemented your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO3gz.png) and it worked just fine. However lets say you forgot the *isInterface* flag on your `INVOKEINTERFACE` instruction *(ASM: MethodInsnNode.itf boolean)*, then you have a problem.

When I attempted to save the modified file with this flag missing the ASM verifier threw an exception, giving the reason `INVOKEINTERFACE can't be used with classes`. When you export a jar with Recaf all your modified files are pre-verified to ensure their bytecode is valid. I actually forgot to put the flag on myself until the verifier window popped up. If I disable the verification process and then export the jar then I get the same VerifyError you just gave.

So to reiterate *this is very likely to have been user-error, but JBytemod didn't catch that*.

Comment: You are right, but there is no checkbox or anything else for setting the `isInterface` flag when adding a `invokeinterface` instruction in JByteMod.